# Output random lines from a large document to a TextBox

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a program that reads a large document, for example the bible, and outputs multiple random lines. I can get it to output one random line, but no others.

The end goal is to have a user input to determine how many lines are displayed.

Here's my code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ' Dim howmanylines As Integer
        ' howmanylines = InputBox("how many lines for paragrpah", "xd",,,)
        'Dim count As Integer = 0
        ' Do Until count = howmanylines
        Dim sr As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\Users\Dumpster Fire\Desktop\bible.doc")
        Dim sr2 As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\Users\Dumpster Fire\Desktop\bible.doc")
        Dim sr3 As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\Users\Dumpster Fire\Desktop\bible.doc")
        Dim xd As Integer = 0
        Dim curline As Integer = 0
        Dim random As Integer = 0
        Do Until sr.EndOfStream = True
            sr.ReadLine()
            xd = xd + 1
        Loop
        sr.Dispose()
        sr.Close()
        Randomize()
        random = Rnd() * xd
        Do Until curline = random
            TextBox1.Text = sr2.ReadLine

            ' curline = curline + 1
            Randomize()
            random = Rnd() * xd

            TextBox1.Text = sr3.ReadLine

            curline = curline + 1

            '   count = count + 1
        Loop
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Have you only one TextBox to display the result? You are overwritting the TextBox1.Text each loop... You would need a list or any kind of collection

Comment: Yeah I only have one text box but I changed it to multiline will that not work??

Comment: No, you are not appending content, you are overwritting it. Try this: TextBox1.Text += sr3.ReadLine

Comment: Hey thanks almost works only problem is now it outputs the same line twice lol

Comment: Your code is not too clear, I do not know why you use 3 StreamReaders, but maybe if you change TextBox1.Text = sr2.ReadLine to TextBox1.Text = "", it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things I would suggest to improve your code.

1. Implement [Using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx). This will ensure that the `StreamReader` is disposed of when finished. It saves you having to remember and it's less lines of code so improves readability.
2. I would consider using [Integer.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx):

   > Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the conversion succeeded.
3. You only need to use one `StreamReader` and add all the lines to a `List(Of String)`.
4. Use a [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) to add your lines too and then output this to the `TextBox` at the end. Note that you will have to import `System.Text` to reference the `StringBuilder` class.
5. Use [Random.Next](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx):

   > Returns a random integer that is within a specified range.

The end result would be something like this:

```
txtLines.Text = ""

Dim howManyLines As Integer = 0
If Integer.TryParse(txtUserInput.Text, howManyLines) Then

    Dim lines As New List(Of String)

    Using sr As New StreamReader("C:\test\test.txt")

        Do Until sr.EndOfStream()
            lines.Add(sr.ReadLine)
        Loop

    End Using

    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    Dim rnd As New Random()

    For i = 0 To howManyLines - 1
        Dim nextLine As Integer = rnd.Next(lines.Count - 1)
        sb.AppendLine(lines(nextLine))
    Next

    txtLines.Text = sb.ToString()

End If
```

You would ideally place this code on a button click event.

Comment: I'm not to good at coding yet but where would I add this section of code 2?

Comment: it depends on how you want to do this. I had a `Button` that I clicked and then read from the `TextBox` the number I inputted. You can add a `Button` to the design and double click it for it to add the handler into your code for you to then add this code to.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help really appreciate it